# Populating data from legacy DB using Entity Framework Code First

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-migration

Basically we are doing a revamp of an old website so we've set up a new application/DB with proper relational schema but we need to bring data over from old system (invalid referential integrity/no fk/sometimes no pk) as each of us work on a module.

Looking at using EF code first as there will be a few of us working on the system.

Will it be best to write SQL script to bring over all these tables to fit the new schema or is there a good way to do this in Code First? like seeding?

Or will this case be suited to going Database First approach where we just bring over data using Generate Script functionality in SSMS?

Would like to hear if anyone's done similar work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off-topic because it's opinion-based. My opinion: use SSIS or ADF.

Answer (score 2):

A one-time migration from the old schema to the new schema would normally be done with SQL scripts, not with EF.  You have to write the transformation logic either way, and with EF you additionally have to create a DbContext model for the old schema, and EF is slower at performing bulk operations.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar task to do: I had to create a completely new web application (App B) with a new database (Db B) based on old ones (App A and Db A). The relations and general structure was a real mess in Db A, so I decided that it was better to generate Db B with a code-first approach and then I created another simple application which would do all the migration stuff. I had 2 contexts from Db A and Db B and all the migration logic was there. It worked like a charm.

As for seeding. It would be better if I could do it with a db seeder in the App B but there was a huge amount of data so it was literally impossible to do that.

Comment: On your migration app how did you bring data from DB A to DB B? That’s the biggest question I have right now.

Comment: As I mentioned, I had 2 db contexts in one application, I couldn't just copy the data from DB A to DB B because the structure was different, so I had to write the migration logic for some entities. The basic flow was like this
Select data from DB A ---> Some migration logic ---> Write processed data to DB B